# Easy html import for development

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I am looking for a good solutions to import html snippets while developing. For those who are familiar with WordPress probably know functions as get_sidebar() etc. I am looking for something that imports a html snippet from a different file so I can keep the file structure modular while developing (I do not need a production solution!).

Is there anyone has a suggestion regarding a decent template engine preferably something that works with javascript.

UPDATE
I am looking for a solution that would work with Js. That would allow me to have a folder structure like:

```
// Snippets
    navbar.html
    sidebar.html
    footer.html
// Pages
    Somepage.html
```

So the navbar are static elements which I would like to import to somepage.html. Therefore I can keep all files separate while I am developing.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: are you creating a static website? Or are you using a dynamic language such PHP?

Comment: I guess you could make an ajax call and insert the returned content into a div

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('sidebar.html') ?>
```

Something like that? Get a file and echo it?

Comment: Yes, However I would prefer something that does not use php so I wont have to set up a local server

Answer (score 1):

SSI(Server Side Includes) may be a good way to import `html` snippets. just like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->
```

or using `jQuery` `AJAX` method `$("#id").load('footer.html')`

Comment: Sounds like he is after the jQuery AJAX method to me